# How to render a Blob in database as pdf using node.js and express?

Tags: node.js, express, db2

I am using DB2 as the database and I have a table which has pdfs stored in one table as BLOB column. I would like to render this blob as a pdf using node.js and express. I have tried a couple of ways but always got the result as corrupted pdf. Here is the code snippet that I tried. Appreciate your suggestions and solutions

```
 app.get('/doc', function(req, res){

    conn.query("select DOCUMENT FROM abc.table WHERE KEY=?",[req.query.id],function(err, DOCUMENT1, moreResultSets) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
                             res.send(new Buffer(DOCUMENT1[0].DOCSOURCE).toString('base64','utf-8')); 
     });  
});
```

Comment: 1) Shouldn't `DOCUMENT1[0].DOCSOURCE` reference the actual column name, `DOCUMENT` in your query? 2) What is `toString('base64','utf-8')` supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Hi Mustacio, Yes that's correct. I have pasted the column name here by mistake as DOCSOURCE I had actually given it as DOCUMNET1[0].DOCUMENT. toString('base64','utf-8') does the base 64 encoding.

Comment: By the way I have tried also without the base64 encoding like res.send(DOCUMENT1[0].DOCUMENT) it still didn't work.

Comment: All documentation I can find for Buffer says that the signature of the function is `toString([encoding], [start], [end])`, so I'm unsure what you are trying to achive with `toString('base64','utf-8')`